# How to return an Observeble within nested Observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observer-pattern

I have two nested observables, the first observable provides an ID which is passed as an argument to the second observable `userTypeID`.

The goal is to return an Observable based on the `actionType` which can either be `view` or `edit` in order to do something like this.

```
// returns view object 
getPresentationFields('view').subscribe(data => console.log(data)); 

// returns edit object
getPresentationFields('edit').subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

However, since I've already subscribed to the Observables within `getPresentationFields(...)`, I can't subscribe to the function itself as written above.

```
getPresentationFields(actionType: string) {
    this.customerService.getUserByID(this.id).subscribe(user => {
        this.presConfigService.getPresConfig(user.userTypeID).pipe(
            flatMap((configs) => configs),          // ----[obj1, obj2, obj3]----
            filter((configs) => configs.show)      // ----obj1----obj2----obj3----
        ).subscribe(() => {
            if(actionType == 'view'){
                // Return View Observable
            }else if(actionType == 'edit'){
                // Return Edit Observable
            }
        });
    });
}
```

How can I return an Observable based on the param passed to `getPresentationFields('view')` or `getPresentationFields('edit')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to subscribe in the `getPresentationFields` code, just pass through the Observable.

Rough example (not sure what part of config you need to return for view/edit)

```js
function getPresentationFields(actionType: string) {
  return this.customerService
    .getUserByID(this.id)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(user => this.presConfigService.getPresConfig(user.userTypeID)),
      flatMap((configs) => configs),
      filter((configs) => {
        if(actionType == 'view'){
          return configs.show;
        }else if(actionType == 'edit'){
          return configs.edit;
        }
      })
    )
}
```

OR you could have an if-else somewhere higher:

```js
function getPresentationFields(actionType: string) {
  const result$ = this.customerService
    .getUserByID(this.id)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(user => this.presConfigService.getPresConfig(user.userTypeID))
    );

 if(actionType == 'view'){
    return result$.pipe(
      // ... get view data
    );
  } else if(actionType == 'edit'){
    return result$.pipe(
      // ... get edit data
    )
  }
}
```

Generally, you need to subscribe to Observable only where you consume results.

*it might even happen that you don't actually subscribe in your code, but pass the observable somewhere outside, like with `angular | async` or `redux effects` !*

So mostly you'll use operators like [switchMap](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/switchMap/), [mergeMap](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/mergeMap/), [combineLatest](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/combineLatest/), etc to process your data and pass it to subscriptions, which would become as thin as possible.